# How to make the output of program running in one terminal be the input of another terminal?

Tags: python, linux, user-interface, io, pipe

NOTE: The problem is based on GUI program, so ordinary pipe won't work, I need keep both program running.

Preparation: In Redhat or Ubuntu, two gnome-terminal opened, terminal A is running a script program, which can generate some string output; terminal B is running another program, which is waiting user input.

Goal: Make the output of the terminal A/program be the input of Terminal B automatically.

The main challenge point is that, the program running in terminal B is beyond my control, it can only take some kind of specific user inputs via keyboard, I can not type any other pipe command while running it. Also, program B need some time to handle the command passed from program A, so if I have more than one command I need to keep both program RUNNING, but not like ordinary pipe: A generate series of command and terminated itself, all commands would be passed to B at the same time, B get input and response. If all commands come at the same time, B can only make response to the first one and ignore the rest.

Till now I have to copy the first program output and paste it into terminal B, is there any clever way to do link two terminal and make this operation automatically?

[image: problem diagram]

Comment: Write the output of P1 to file, then read the file from P2, maybe?

Comment: well I considered this solution, but P2 can only take keyboard input or stdin as controller, I can't let it do reading operation......So I need to make the output of P1 flushed to P2 every time but not only one time when P1 terminated

Comment: You often use Unix Domain Sockets for the fastest IPC on Linux. Also see [Which Linux IPC technique to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2281204/608639), [Interprocess communication in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6920858/608639), [Interprocess communication via Pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43412558/608639), [Interprocess Communication via file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11062444/608639), [Interprocess Communication in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1343626/608639), etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Interprocess communication in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6920858/608639). You often use Unix Domain Sockets for the fastest IPC on Linux. Also see [Which Linux IPC technique to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2281204/608639), [Interprocess communication via Pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43412558/608639), [Interprocess Communication via file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11062444/608639), [Interprocess Communication in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1343626/608639), etc.

Answer (score 0):

In one way, I recommend changing the way to connect these terminals.

Or, you could try`/dev/tty` file.

> /dev/tty is a special file, representing the terminal for the current
>   process. So, when you echo 1 > /dev/tty, your message ('1') will
>   appear on your screen. Likewise, when you cat /dev/tty, your
>   subsequent input gets duplicated (until you press Ctrl-C).
>
> /dev/tty doesn't 'contain' anything as such, but you can read from it
>   and write to it (for what it's worth). I can't think of a good use for
>   it, but there are similar files which are very useful for simple IO
>   operations (e.g. /dev/ttyS0 is normally your serial port)

It does make your command to pass to the terminals, but I am not sure you could exec them with this way.